# Read From Text File "dictionary.txt"

Tags: java

Below is an example of my code. I have a text file called dictionary.txt that I am trying to read from and I keep getting an error in the constructor line. I am unsure how to build the constructor to read the dictionary.txt file and how that interacts with `name = new File("dictionary.txt");`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordLists{

    //instance variables
    private String[] words; //array of words taken in 
    private int wordCount;
    private File name;
    private Boolean hasLetter;

    //constructor    
    public WordLists(String "WHAT GOES HERE?") throws FileNotFoundException {
        //throws exception because it takes and scans a file
        wordCount=0;
        name=new File("dictionary.txt");
        hasLetter=null;
        Scanner listScanner=new Scanner(name);

        while(listScanner.hasNextLine()){
            listScanner.nextLine();
            wordCount++;
        }

        listScanner.close();
        words=new String [wordCount];
        Scanner secondScanner=new Scanner(name);

        for(int i=0; i<wordCount; i++){
            words[i]=secondScanner.nextLine();
        }

        secondScanner.close();
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting and what line does it point to.

Comment: It is pointing to the the line under the //constructor comment, I am getting the FileNotFoundException thrown. There is a dictionary.txt file to read from but for some reason it is not accepting the array parameter

Comment: The way you currently have it setup, nothing goes there. You could do `String filePath` there then do `name = new File(filePath);`

Comment: Then where will it read the file dictionary.txt from? I am sorry if that sounds dumb, I am new to java and this is the first time I am trying to read from a txt file.

Comment: Where is dictionary.txt stored?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying it throws a file not found exception in the constructor, say it at the class name. If that doesn’t work, try a try catch syntax instead of throwing an exception in the class

Answer (score 0):

The String in the constructor line should be a variable corresponding to the file path of the .txt file you're trying to read.

Additionally, work on formatting your code to make it easier to read. With formatting, adding in the string variable to the constructor, and then a main method to run the whole thing, the finished class should look something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class WordLists {

    //instance variables
    private String[] words; //array of words taken in 
    private int wordCount;
    private File name;
    private Boolean hasLetter;
    Scanner listScanner, secondScanner;

    //constructor    
    public WordLists(String path) throws FileNotFoundException{
        //throws exception because it takes and scans a file
        wordCount = 0;
        name = new File(path);
        hasLetter = false;

        listScanner = new Scanner(name);
        secondScanner = new Scanner(name);

        while(listScanner.hasNextLine()){
            listScanner.nextLine();
            wordCount++;
        }

        words = new String [wordCount];

        for(int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++){
            words[i] = secondScanner.nextLine();
        }

        listScanner.close();
        secondScanner.close(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try { 
            WordLists w = new WordLists("dictionary.txt");
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```